# ModuleNotFoundError when import from constants file in python

Tags: python

```
app-main-folder
    /local
        /__init__.py
        /run.py
    constants.py
```

I am trying to import from constants in `run.py` it's throwing this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "local/run.py", line 4, in <module>
    from init import app
  File "/home/manavarthivenkat/ANUESERVICES--BACKEND/local/init.py", line 5, in <module>
    from constants import BaseConstants
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'constants'
```

Comment: You didn't install the package so it can't be found and imported.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Comment: type `pip list` to see if the module is installed.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install constants
```

Try this on your shell
and try running run.py

make sure you load the constants library

Comment: what if constants.py is module i have written and already present in the current file structure mentioned above

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

this is because Python assumes all your python files are in the current directory. you should tell the compiler you are looking for the file somewhere else.

```
from app-main-folder.constants import constants # assuming constants is the name of your class in that constants.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sys.path.append` to tell Python interpreter where to search the modules.

First, you can check the current Python path

```
import sys
from pprint import pprint
pprint(sys.path)
```

If the path to the directory of `constants.py` is not included in the output, you can manually add that path, by

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/constants.py")
```